# ZF2 / Navigation ACL / accept doesn't work if an asserter is provided

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, acl

I have a `member` role with a resource `platform.ticketing` and a privilege `access`.

Acl is defined such as below :

```
$this->allow('member', 'platform.ticketing', 'access', new HasTicketing());
```

`HasTicketing` is a simple asserter returning `true` if member can access or `false` if not.

If I remove asserter, everything works fine but the menu appears ...

On my navigation config :

```
// ...
[
    'label'     => 'Ticketing',
    'route'     => 'platform/ticketing',
    'resource'  => 'platform.ticketing',
    'privilege' => 'access',
],
// ...
```

On navigation partial :

```
// ...
foreach($this->container->getPages() as $page) {
    if(!$page->isVisible() || !$this->navigation()->accept($page)) continue;
// ...
```

Please, check the Xdebug trace at the returning of `accept()` ZF `AclListener` class

[image: Acl Xdebug Trace]

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to replicate the problem using Zend Framework v2.5.1 and the Skeleton Application:

*module/Application/config/module.config.php*

```php
return array(
    // ...
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'home',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Page #1',
                'route' => 'home',
                'resource'  => 'mvc:admin',
                'privilege' => 'access',
                'pages' => array(
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Child #1',
                        'route' => 'home',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Page #2',
                'route' => 'home',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        // ...
        'factories' => array(
            'my-navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            // ...
        ),
    ),
    // ...
);
```

*module/Application/Module.php*

```php
namespace Application;

use Application\Acl\Assertion;
use Zend\View\HelperPluginManager;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl as ZendAcl;

class Module
{
    // ...
    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                // This will overwrite the native navigation helper
                'navigation' => function(HelperPluginManager $pm) {
                    $assertion = new Assertion\TestAssertion();

                    // Setup ACL:
                    $acl = new ZendAcl\Acl();
                    $acl->addRole(new ZendAcl\Role\GenericRole('member'));
                    $acl->addRole(new ZendAcl\Role\GenericRole('admin'));
                    $acl->addResource(new ZendAcl\Resource\GenericResource('mvc:admin'));
                    $acl->addResource(new ZendAcl\Resource\GenericResource('mvc:community.account'));
                    $acl->allow('member', 'mvc:community.account');

                    $acl->allow('admin', 'mvc:admin', 'access', $assertion);
//                    $acl->allow('admin', 'mvc:admin', 'access');

                    // Get an instance of the proxy helper
                    $navigation = $pm->get('Zend\View\Helper\Navigation');

                    // Store ACL and role in the proxy helper:
                    $navigation->setAcl($acl)->setRole('admin');

                    // Return the new navigation helper instance
                    return $navigation;
                }
            )
        );
    // ...
}
```

*module/Application/src/Application/Acl/Assertion/TestAssertion.php*

```php
namespace Application\Acl\Assertion;

use Zend\Permissions\Acl as ZendAcl;

class TestAssertion implements ZendAcl\Assertion\AssertionInterface
{
    public function assert(ZendAcl\Acl $acl,
                           ZendAcl\Role\RoleInterface $role = null,
                           ZendAcl\Resource\ResourceInterface $resource = null,
                           $privilege = null)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

*module/Application/view/application/index/index.phtml*

```php
<?php $this->navigation('my-navigation')->menu()->setPartial('application/partials/menu') ?>
<?php echo $this->navigation('my-navigation')->menu(); ?>
```

*module/Application/view/application/partials/menu.phtml*

```php
<?php
foreach($this->container->getPages() as $page) {
    if (!$page->isVisible() || !$this->navigation()->accept($page)) {
        continue;
    }

    echo $this->navigation()->menu()->htmlify($page) . '<br />';
}
```

With `Application\Acl\Assertion\TestAssertion::assert()` returning **true**, "Page #1" menu link is displayed.

[image: "Page #1" menu link displayed]

With `Application\Acl\Assertion\TestAssertion::assert()` returning **false**, "Page #1" menu link is not displayed.

[image: "Page #1" menu link is not displayed]

If you remove the `$assertion` in `Application\Module::getViewHelperConfig()`, `$acl->allow('admin', 'mvc:admin', 'access');`, the link will render again. This is because the role (admin) will have access to the resource (mvc:admin) and privilege (access).

The above leads me to believe that you are either using a dated version of Zend Framework or `Application\Acl\Asserter\HasTracking::assert()` isn't returning the boolean you are expecting.

Comment: thanks for your answer, my assertion returns true or false. And my version of ZF is 2.3.3. I will try to update it and test again ...

Comment: Damn, the cause is the assertion ... for the navigation, `$role` is `Zend\Permission\Acl\Role\GenericRole` instance ! and for pages, `$role` is my `User entity` instance ... So, in the first case, assertion returns `false` because of `if (($role instanceof User) && ...))` ...

Comment: Great to hear you found the root of the issue. Without being able to see inside of the assertion I wasn't able to dive any further. Any chance I could score an upvote for the answer? Shooting to get some ad's disabled :)